# Filling a specific column based on user inputs and tracking result

Tags: excel, vba

I have range of products that are routinely tested every quarter, each product is tested once annually.

I need an excel VBA that prompts the user to input what product was tested and then prompt the user to input in which quarter (e.g. Q1,Q2 etc ) the product was tested. Then in a specific column this information about which quarter the product is tested is displayed and inputted into a cell.

I then want to be able to keep track of this information about which quarter each product was tested every year so for the next test for each product, would like excel to fill the row next to it. Shown below is an visual example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Example of Excel Worksheet

[image: Example of Excel Worksheet]

Also attached is the code I have been trying mould to fit my problem.

```
Dim myValue As Variant

myValue = InputBox("Give me some input")

Dim SearchString As String
Dim SearchRange As Range, cl As Range
Dim FirstFound As String
Dim sh As Worksheet

' Set Search value
SearchString = myValue
Application.FindFormat.Clear
' loop through all sheets
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
   ' Find first instance on sheet
   Set cl = sh.Cells.Find(What:=SearchString, _
       After:=sh.Cells(1, 1), _
       LookIn:=xlValues, _
       LookAt:=xlPart, _
       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
       SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
       MatchCase:=False, _
       SearchFormat:=False)
   If Not cl Is Nothing Then
       ' if found, remember location
       FirstFound = cl.Address
       ' format found cell
       Do
           cl.Font.Bold = True
           cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
           ' find next instance
           Set cl = sh.Cells.FindNext(After:=cl)
           ' repeat until back where we started
       Loop Until FirstFound = cl.Address
   End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain what your actual question is? How is the code not working?

Comment: Your macro identifies the correct row so I guess you want help determining the correct column. ?  Is Year1 , Year2 different for each product or is it fixed for example Year1 = 2019, Year2 = 2020 etc ?

Comment: @CDP1802 Hi there, Just a note my VBA skills are quite basic. Yes the macro identifies the correct row but I think there has to be easier Macro to solve this problem. Each Year is fixed so for example Product A is tested in Q3 in 2020 then Q2 in 2021 etc. Would you have any idea in how to solve this problem -Thanks.

Comment: @BigBen Hi there, My question is to prompt the user to input what was tested e.g Product A then again prompt the user to input the quarter that it was tested and then for every year the next test for each product, I would like excel to fill the row next to it e.g fill year 1, then fill year 2 etc -Thanks

Comment: 'would like excel to fill the row next to it.'. Did you mean the column next to it ? If you changed the column headings to 'Qu Tested 2020', 'Qu Tested 2021' etc then you could ask the user for the product id and date it was tested. You then put that date in the correct column but display it as a QU number. I think that makes the process more robust against erroneous user entry.

Comment: @CDP1802 Thanks,Yes the column, I'm not sure how to go about coding it in VBA. Would you have any suggestions?

Comment: If for instance column 5 is 2019 and the date 01/06/19 then YEAR(date) - 2019 + 5 = 5 which is the column to put the QU in. To get the QU (sorry, I was wrong there isn't a QU option) set cell value to INT((MONTH(date)+2)/3) but first test for valid date.

Comment: @CDP1802 How would this be coded based on user prompts as I want the user to input the product that was tested and which quarter the product was tested. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have this line to get the product

```
myValue = InputBox("Give me some input")
```

Just add another line to get the Quarter

```
myValue2 = InputBox("Give me some more input")
```

The search command is working correctly although it could be made more efficient by restricting the search to the first column not the whole sheet.

```
Set cl = sh.Cells.Find(What:=SearchString, _
   After:=sh.Cells(1, 1), _
   LookIn:=xlValues, _
   LookAt:=xlPart, _
   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
   SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
   MatchCase:=False, _
   SearchFormat:=False)
```

To match the whole string rather than a part change the parameter LookAt:=xlWhole.

If you only have one product that matches the user input then this code can be deleted.

```
Do
   cl.Font.Bold = True
   cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
   ' find next instance
   Set cl = sh.Cells.FindNext(After:=cl)
   ' repeat until back where we started
Loop Until FirstFound = cl.Address
```

The row number is found simply with

```
rowno = cl.Row
```

The next part you seem to be having difficulty with is locating the next available 
blank column in that row. The VBA is as a user would do by using Ctrl-CursorLeft
from the end column.

```
colno = ws.range(rowno,Columns.count).End(xlToLeft.Column +1
```

Since it's very unlikely your sheet will span more 702 years this might be clearer

```
colno = ws.range("ZZ" & rowno).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
```

Now update that cell

```
wc.cell(rowno,colno) = Value2
```

Put those components together using sensible variable names, add some validation on what the user is entering, insert some debugging messages at critical points and you should get something like this ;

```
  Sub enterdata()

      Const DBUG As Boolean = False ' set to TRUE to see each step
      Const YR1COL = 5 'E

      Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
      Set wb = ThisWorkbook

      Dim sProduct As String
      Dim iRowno As Long, iQu As Integer, iColno As Integer
      Dim rng As Range, iLastRow As Long, wsMatch As Worksheet, cellMatch As Range
      Dim chances As Integer: chances = 3

  LOOP1:     ' get valid product
      sProduct = InputBox(Title:="Input Product", prompt:="Product is ")
      If DBUG Then Debug.Print sProduct

      If Len(sProduct) > 0 Then
          ' search  through all sheets
          For Each ws In wb.Sheets
              iLastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
              If DBUG Then Debug.Print ws.Name & " " & iLastRow

              ' Search col A of sheet using xlWhole for exact match
              Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & iLastRow) ' avoid header
              Set cellMatch = rng.Find( _
                What:=sProduct, _
                After:=rng.Cells(2, 1), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False)

              ' exit on first match
              If Not cellMatch Is Nothing Then
                  Set wsMatch = ws
                  GoTo LOOP2
              End If
          Next
      Else
          Exit Sub
      End If

      ' no match so try again
      If cellMatch Is Nothing Then
          chances = chances - 1
          If chances < 1 Then
              MsgBox "Too many tries", vbCritical, "Exiting"
              Exit Sub
          End If
          MsgBox sProduct & " NOT FOUND - " & chances & " tries left", vbExclamation, "Error"
          GoTo LOOP1
      End If

  LOOP2:

      iRowno = cellMatch.Row
      If DBUG Then Debug.Print wsMatch.Name & " Row = " & iRowno

      ' determine column
      With wsMatch
          iColno = .Cells(iRowno, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
          If iColno < YR1COL Then iColno = YR1COL ' start in E
      End With

      wsMatch.Activate
      wsMatch.Cells(iRowno, iColno).Select
      If DBUG Then
          wsMatch.Cells(iRowno, iColno).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 ' yellow
          Debug.Print "Column = " & iColno
      End If
      If DBUG Then MsgBox "Target cell " & wsMatch.Name & " Row " & iRowno & " Col " & iColno, vbInformation

      chances = 3
  LOOP3: ' get valid QU
      iQu = Application.InputBox(Title:="Input Quarter", prompt:="Test Qu (1-4) for " & sProduct, Type:=1) ' type 1 number
      If iQu = 0 Then
         GoTo LOOP1
      ElseIf iQu > 4 Then
           chances = chances - 1
           If chances < 1 Then
               MsgBox "Too many tries", vbExclamation, "Error"
               Exit Sub
           End If
           MsgBox iQu & " NOT VALID - " & chances & " tries left", vbExclamation, "Error"
           GoTo LOOP3
      End If

      ' Update sheet
      wsMatch.Cells(iRowno, iColno) = iQu
      If DBUG Then wsMatch.Cells(iRowno, iColno).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 ' green
      MsgBox "Product=" & sProduct & vbCr _
         & wsMatch.Name & " Row=" & iRowno & " Col=" & iColno & " Qu=" & iQu, vbInformation, "Updated"

      GoTo LOOP1 ' next product

  End Sub
```